# Is it possible to create XBAP applications with Expression Blend 3 only?

Tags: expression-blend, xbap

I want to create an XBAP application with blend, but when click on

- File
- New Project

it asks me if I want to create:

- Silverlight 3 Application + Website --or--
- WPF Application

Is there a way to create XBAPs from Expression Blend 3 or does this require Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Basically an XBAP page inherits from System.Windows.Controls.Page,so you create

```
public partial class Page1 : System.Windows.Controls.Page
```

So you should be able to create and design the page in Expression Blend,try WPF Application option.

For publishing you need Visual Studio....

- http://blogs.msdn.com/maximelamure/archive/2007/01/24/create-your-own-pfx-file-for-clickonce.aspx http://www.xbap.org/faq.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/aa700831.aspx
- Or C# Express with extensions.